# SQL Server : how to include nullable grouping values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL Query

```
SELECT
    cs.group,
    cs.code,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN datepart(mm,cs.scheduledate) = 1 THEN cs.amount ELSE 0 END),0) as a_jan,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN datepart(mm,cs.scheduledate) = 2 THEN cs.amount ELSE 0 END),0) as a_feb,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN datepart(mm,cs.scheduledate) = 3 THEN cs.amount ELSE 0 END),0) as a_mar,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN datepart(mm,cs.scheduledate) = 4 THEN cs.amount ELSE 0 END),0) as a_abr,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN datepart(mm,cs.scheduledate) = 5 THEN cs.amount ELSE 0 END),0) as a_may,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN datepart(mm,cs.scheduledate) = 6 THEN cs.amount ELSE 0 END),0) as a_jun,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN datepart(mm,cs.scheduledate) = 7 THEN cs.amount ELSE 0 END),0) as a_jul,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN datepart(mm,cs.scheduledate) = 8 THEN cs.amount ELSE 0 END),0) as a_ago,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN datepart(mm,cs.scheduledate) = 9 THEN cs.amount ELSE 0 END),0) as a_sep,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN datepart(mm,cs.scheduledate) = 10 THEN cs.amount ELSE 0 END),0) as a_oct,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN datepart(mm,cs.scheduledate) = 11 THEN cs.amount ELSE 0 END),0) as a_nov,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN datepart(mm,cs.scheduledate) = 12 THEN cs.amount ELSE 0 END),0) as a_dic,
    ISNULL(SUM(cs.amount),0) as a_cds
FROM
    employee_statement cs
WHERE
    datepart(yyyy,cs.startdate) = 2018
GROUP BY
    cs.group,
    cs.code
```

This query returns a table like this:

[image]

**GROUP** is a dynamic value that I could have hardcoded because doesn't change too much and **CODE** is a fixed value list.

So what I need is that no matter if there is no row for specific `GROUP` or `CODE` I get the row with 0 value.

Example:

[image]

Any clue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CROSS JOIN` to generate the rows and a `LEFT JOIN` and `GROUP BY` to get the results you want:

The structure of the query looks like this:

```
select g.group, c.code, . . .
from (select distinct group from employee_statement) g cross join
     (select distinct code from employee_statement) c left join
     employee_statement cs
     on cs.group = g.group and cs.code = c.code and
        cs.startdate >= '2018-01-01' and cs.startdate < '2019-01-01'
group by g.group, c.code;
```

Note that I changed the `where` clause to be date comparisons.  Using a function generally means the optimizer will not use an index.

Another note.  I would calculate the computed columns as:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN month(cs.scheduledate) = 1 THEN cs.amount ELSE 0 END) as a_jan,
```

That is neither `ISNULL()` nor `COALESCE()` (my preferred version) is needed, because you have `ELSE 0`.  I think `MONTH()` is more understandable than `DATEPART()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried it that way and im getting same results :) any clue?

Comment: @VAAA . . . Yes.  The `where` conditions should be in the `on` clause (I changed the answer).